# I have removed the NmeaListener from LocationManager, why the NmeaListener's onNmeaReceived() still be call?

Tags: android, nmea

Here are my sample code:

```
    public class GeoPointMapNewActivity extends Activity implements GpsStatus.NmeaListener {
        private LocationManager mLocationManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.geopointmapnew_layout);
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            mLocationManager.addNmeaListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
            //i have call removeNmeaListener, but this method still be call?
            mLocationManager.removeNmeaListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            //******
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            //******
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            //*******
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem even if I remove it and set it to null. Have you found a solution to this problem ?